# How to Integrate monaco editor with monaco-languageclient using js library?

Tags: angularjs, monaco-editor, monaco-languageserver

I am working on an Angularjs project and want to integrate monaco editor with its language server using js library.

Comment: Have you tried something like this? https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient/